# Running yolov3 demo using jetson nano and rpi camera

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, yolo, darknet, nvidia-jetson

I am using **nvidia jetson nano** with rpi camera to run **yolov3**, i'm 100% sure that the camera is compatible and working perfectly.
when I tried to run live demo using this command

> ./darknet detector demo data/yolo.data cfg/yolov3_custom_train.cfg
>   yolov3_custom_train_3000.weights -c 0
>
> CUDA-version: 10000 (10000), cuDNN: 7.6.3, GPU count: 1 OpenCV
>   version: 4.3.0 Demo net.optimized_memory = 0

i get the following warnings

> [ WARN:0] global
>   /home/jn/opencv_build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp
>   (1759) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video
>   playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Internal data stream error.
>   [ WARN:0] global
>   /home/jn/opencv_build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp
>   (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline [
>   WARN:0] global
>   /home/jn/opencv_build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp
>   (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer:
>   pipeline have not been created

then the demo window pops up and i get a constant green screen

is there any recommended solution?

[the green screen i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNVnr.png)

Comment: can you provide more details where you get darknet, version and perhaps a way to re-create the issue. 
from what i understand, yolov3 is supporting OpenCV 3.x